# MySQL select records for the past 3 months

Tags: mysql

what will be the smartest way to select all rows from MySQL table for the past 3 months if the table has the following columns:

```
| id (int) | year (int)| month (int) |
```

Considering that if the current month & year are for example **2.2016**   I need to select all records for 11.2015 & 12.2015 & 1.2016

It is easy if the current month is greater than 3 because all months that I need to select are in the same year so I can subtract 3 from the current month and run simple query

```
SELECT * FROM mytabe where year=2016 and month >= xx
```

Comment: If you show us some ways, we'll tell you which is smartest.

Comment: @Strawberry what i meant is  that i can write some if/else statements in php and prepare few different queries but I don't think this is the beset approach

Comment: Well, the smartest approach is probably to store year and month (and possibly day) as a single entity.

Comment: Yes I can't agree more, but there is nothing I can do here. I can only use what I have from the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select * from mytable where STR_TO_DATE(concat(year,"-",month,"-01"),'%Y-%m-%d')>date_sub(curdate(),Interval 3 month) ;
```

The above query will get fetch year and month from date 3 months before today

Comment: > year? not >= ?? also, try that with curdate() in Jan or Feb, you would get the previous year and month (i.e. the month will be 11 or 12) how does month 1 get to be > than 11 or 12?

Comment: @Used_By_Already thanks for your input I have updated my answer

Comment: @Undefined_variable yes your query works with just two corrections - you've missed **WHERE** after mytable and instead if Interval 3 months it should be **Interval 3 month** without an **s**

`SELECT * FROM `mytabe` WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`Year`,"-",`Month`,"-01"),'%Y-%m-%d')>DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 3 MONTH)`

Comment: @metost made the changes

Comment: well done. of course storing a date would be preferable, but doesn't detract from this solution

Comment: I agree but in comments @metost said he can't change table structure

Answer (score 3):

You can select three **Months** records by these queries follow this. 
The columnName means  which column data want you select.
The tableName means  which table data want you select.
The dateColumnName means which  column date base you want to select data.

It would return **Last Month** data from today.

```
SELECT columName FROM tableName WHERE dateColumName BETWEEN ( DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND Date(Now())
```

It would return **Second Last Month** data from today.

```
SELECT columName FROM tableName WHERE dateColumName BETWEEN ( DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND ( DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

It would return **Third Last Month** data from today.

```
SELECT columName FROM tableName WHERE dateColumName BETWEEN ( DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AND ( DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
```

May It help to others.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
Select * from mytable where STR_TO_DATE(concat(year,"-",month,"-01"),'%Y-%m-%d')>date_sub(curdate(),Interval 3 month) ;
```

Comment: Can you add a short description?