# Modify SQL query to get data only from past 2 months

Tags: mysql, database, record

Please help me modify the following query to extract only records made in the past 2 months.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM course_participants 
WHERE course_id = courses.id 
WHERE YEAR(created) = 2019)
```

Now it gets results from current year, I need to get the results from the past 2 months.

Thanks!

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35173726/mysql-select-records-for-the-past-3-months) . I think it has been answered before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL select records for the past 3 months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35173726/mysql-select-records-for-the-past-3-months)

Comment: I would most likely would go for `created >=  (NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH)`

Answer (score 2):

You can try below -

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM course_participants 
    WHERE created>=now()-interval 2 month
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Month-function](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/functions/month-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) 
FROM 
  course_participants 
WHERE 
  course_id = courses.id and
  YEAR(created) = 2019 and 
  MONTH(created) in (4,5)
```

If the date should not be fix, but depend on the current date. you can check out the [Dateadd-Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: have you ever executed this type of query before with two where clause? if op mistakenly post his question do you need to follow the same in time of answering?

Comment: No i did not. I was hunting for reputation. You are right, i should have taken the time to test my answere before posting it. Sorry i will do better next time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your query to return records from the past two months dynamically, then you can add a DATE_ADD expression in your WHERE clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM course_participants WHERE course_id = courses.id and
   created > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -2 MONTH)
```

This takes the current date and goes back 2 months. You can see some documentation on the function [here.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

Comment: We don't like w3schools ([w3fools](https://www.w3fools.com/)) documentation link with a reason, please link to the official documention [MySQL's DATE_ADD(..)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) .

Comment: *"What is this reason?"* [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20110412103745/http://w3fools.com/) is the reason

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks for your comment. I deleted mine after noticing your link, but it seems w3fools have changed their tune since anyway. I've edited my post to link to the official documentation as that is a better resource regardless.

Comment: iam pretty sure if we would look on w3schools iam pretty sure we still find onlogical/bad/incomplete statements/code..

Answer (score 0):

You can substract 2 months from the current date.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM course_participants WHERE course_id = courses.id AND created >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
```

Comment: with two where clause how it can be correct ans? Before answering make your syntax correct first